# Issue with mouse scrolling on a datasheet view when using ie9 and SP2007?

Tags: 2007, datasheet

I had a user today who had some issues with the datasheet view, her browser was updated by IT to IE9 and then I was asked to look at the dataview issues which were down to permission level.

All Good!

But... about 30mins later the user was saying the mouse no longer scrolled. What was interesting is that the scrolling works inside a cell, but not in the headers, the user also used to be able to enter the first character and it would jump ... this also no longer works.

If you take the list out of datasheet view and put in standard view, scrolling in the header works, so it's definitely something to do with the datasheet view and ie9.

Anyone have any thoughts? I have tried compatibility mode, the SP2007 is SP2.

Comment: We're having the same issue with IE9 and SP2007.  I'm hoping someone can crack this one.

Answer (score 1):

There are known issues with IE9 with the ActiveX controls from SharePoint 2007 (and Project Server 2007).  For some, setting the compatibility mode of the pages in the Master Page to quarks or IE 7 mode has helped.

In the HEAD of your Master Page, try:

< meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=5" / >

or

< meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" / >

FYI - IE 5 sets it to quarks mode.